Debug Unresponsive HTTP Request from NodeJS
I am doing an HTTP request via axios to an external API. This works with curl or even the same node JS code when run locally but it is non-responsive when the node code is deployed to google cloud function. Is there any way to debug the TCP layer where is it getting stuck. I tried setting time out option but the error I get logged is the time out error not the original error which keep the call (without timeout ) stuck.
I have seen this happening in local curl (-v) also in some cases i.e. stream did not end etc but after something it passes locally but there no verbose equivalent in axios. Can any other library like request or fetch has such debug feature where I can get verbose log during a HTTP request/>

Can you share more? A piece of code to let us reproduce/understand deeper your issue
